# using multi httpwebrequest to call webservice in timer not working

Tags: c#, wpf, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I experience issue in calling the same URL using  (Windows Phone App)

```
HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/webservice.svc/Getnewtick")) as HttpWebRequest
```

I use this request inside function and this function work on a timer, i have check the traffic using fiddler and i found that first request working will but the second not send and new request to the server , can you advise me (Note i have put message-box inside the function and its appear well on the time thats mean the timer working fine)

This is my code upon your request:-

```
private void FireRequest3(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/webservice.svc/Getnewtick")) as HttpWebRequest
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar))
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var outerRoot2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject2>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject2>(outerRoot2.d);

                    DispatchInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        foreach (var Symbols1 in root.Symbols)
                        {
                            foreach (var nnn in DataReceivedCollection)
                            {
                                var symbolIDintold = Convert.ToInt16(nnn.symid);
                                var symbolIDintnew = Convert.ToInt16(Symbols1.I);
                                var BidStr = Convert.ToString(Symbols1.B);
                                var AskStr = Convert.ToString(Symbols1.B);

                                if (symbolIDintold == symbolIDintnew)
                                {
                                    nnn.textSecond = BidStr;
                                    nnn.textThird = AskStr;

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    });

                }
            }

        }

    }, request);
}
```

and the start button with the timer is :-

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    newTimer.Tick += FireRequest3;
    newTimer.Start();

}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that actually performs the request (and the timer)?

Comment: you can check now, thank you

Comment: did you have any suggestion silent ?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with simplifying your sample, e.g. by replacing the entire inner part with `var foo = reader.ReadToEnd();` - if this helps, then you know where to look next for the error.

If this doesn't help, then try with a (much) longer interval. In some of my apps I found that only X instances of HttpWebRequest can be active at any given time, with X being somewhere between 1 and 8 and might or might not be related to the request address. I ended up with a helper class which enqueues all requests (together with their responses), so that only one HttpWebRequest exists at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it like this i  change the header like this:-

```
HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/webservice.svc/Getnewtick")) as HttpWebRequest


if (request.Headers == null)
    {
        request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    }
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```